# Cuales són las reglas de integridad en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo este ejercicio que me pide la regla de integridad:

a. Añade la regla de integridad para que el estado de la tabla S sea siempre superior a 0.

¿Cual és la regla de integridad?

Comment: Es la regla que dicta que una base de datos siempre mantenga información real

Comment: A vale, muchas gracias!

Comment: yo la verdad no se de que estan hablando. y @Lixus si sabes de lo que esta hablando (es de integridad referencial? que tiene que ver que sea superior a 0?) podrias aclarar la pregunta y poner una respuesta?

Comment: Por favor puedes explicar mejor tu pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las reglas de integridad son justamente reglas que aseguran la consistencia de los datos en una base de datos relacional. Hay tres tipos de reglas o restricciones:

- **De dominio**: A cada atributo está asociado un dominio de valores posibles. Por ejemplo: el número de hijos de un empleado no puede ser negativo, los estados de un  cliente podrían ser pendiente, activo, inactivo, el estado en tu ejemplo debe ser superior a cero.
- **De las entidades**: Ningún componente de la clave primaria de la relación base puede aceptar nulos. Es decir, toda entidada tiene que tener una clave primaria y esta no puede ser nula.
- **Referencial**: La BD no debe contener valores de clave
  ajena sin concordancia. Por ejemplo, en una entidad "Clientes" que tiene un campo PaisId que hace referencia a una entidad "Paises", no debiera existir un relación a un país inexistente.

Tu pregunta no deja del todo claro qué tipo de regla de integridad te están pidiendo definir, pareciera ser del "tipo "de dominio", no lo tengo muy claro con MySql, pero te copio igual un ejemplo de cómo restringir el valor de una columna:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
  user_type enum('ADMIN', 'AGENT', 'CUSTOMER') NOT NULL default 'CUSTOMER',
  estado int not null CHECK (estado > 0)
);
```

Nota: Tal como me hizo notar @Xint0, la clausula `CHECK` es ignorada por MySql, en cuyo caso la única alternativa es implementar un trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER users_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare msg varchar(128);
    IF (new.estado <= 0) THEN
        set msg = concat('users_before_insert: Estado: ', cast(new.estado as char), ' debe ser mayor a 0');
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Cabe notar que en MySQL se ignora la cláusula `CHECK` del comando `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Gracias me ha servido. Al final he puesto "UNSIGNED" a todos los "INT" para que no me de negativo.

Comment: Es cierto @Xint0, `The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. See Section 1.8.2.3, “Foreign Key Differences”.`, ahora edito alternativa